# colorControlHighlight doesn't change color of flat button when pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button

I need to change color of materials flat/borderless button when the user clicks on it. My current setup works for raised buttons, but doesn't work for the borderless button.

Style I use, the `colorControlHighlight` should change the color when pressed?:

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_color</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
```

Layout item:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_SignUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton" />
```

Why does raised buttons work but not borderless?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change is something similar to this

In styles.xml put this

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/button_highlight</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/button_highlight</item>
</style>
```

and in xml layout for Button add this as the button theme

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
//Other parameters as usual
/>
```

Comment: Why is parent Theme.Appcompat.Light and not Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored?

Comment: You need to specify the application theme aligned with your application

Answer (score 0):

Change the parent name as follow : (without the "Borderless.Colored")

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_color</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as "android:theme" like you just did.

Comment: Thanks - but won't this just make it a normal button then? need a flat one

Comment: Hi @cfl , Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Manukumar sorry I cannot remember exactly, only difference I see I'm my code is this: 
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_color_dark</item> maybe see if that solves it